# How to use optimization technique in r to transform variables for linear regression?

Tags: r, linear-regression, nonlinear-optimization

I am trying to **transform variables** for **linear Regression** that can give me the best Rsquare for the model (optimize the cost function - reduce error).

> This is very easy to do using **Excel solver** but I don't know how to
> do it in R. Excel solver & this whole task is demonstrated here which I am trying to
> replicate in r: [Same done using Excel solver](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hC0CKNjv9SM&list=PLdaWFt7A-Gf22hlttVYYoR0HlJ-B7OYwo&index=9)

The variable need to be transformed like: `var_transformed = var + lag(var_transfrm)*beta)^alpha` which I have done below in **step 2 & 3**.

the best values that need to be figured out by **optimizer** is `alpha` & `beta` constants for vars transformation that will help in generating best **lm model / minimize error**.

**1. creating df**

```
library(tidyverse)

df_test <- tribble(
 ~sales, ~var1, ~var2,
  22, 230.1,  37.8,
  10, 44.5,  39.3,
  9,  17.2,  45.9,
  19, 151.5,  41.3,
  13, 180.8,  10.8,
  7,  8.7,    48.9,
  12, 57.5,   32.8,
  13, 120.2,  19.6,
  5,  8.6,    2.1,
  11, 199.8,  2.6)
```

**2. constants that need to be solved for appropriate value**

```
alpha1 = .1
beta1 = .1

alpha2 = .1
beta2 = .1
```

**3. transforming variables for lm using above constants**

this concept is based on `adstock` & `diminishing returns`.

```
df_test  <- df_test %>% 
  mutate(var1_transfrm = var1^alpha1,
         var1_transfrm = if_else(row_number() == 1, 
                               var1^alpha1,
                               ( (var1 + lag(var1_transfrm)*beta1)^alpha1 )
                               ) ,
         
         var2_transfrm = var2^alpha2,
         var2_transfrm = if_else(row_number() == 1, 
                               var2^alpha2,
                               ( (var2 + lag(var2_transfrm)*beta2)^alpha2 )
                               ) 
         )

df_test
```

```
A tibble: 10 × 5
   sales  var1  var2 var1_transfrm var2_transfrm
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>
 1    22 230.   37.8          1.72          1.44
 2    10  44.5  39.3          1.46          1.44
 3     9  17.2  45.9          1.33          1.47
 4    19 152.   41.3          1.65          1.45
 5    13 181.   10.8          1.68          1.27
 6     7   8.7  48.9          1.24          1.48
 7    12  57.5  32.8          1.50          1.42
 8    13 120.   19.6          1.61          1.35
 9     5   8.6   2.1          1.24          1.08
10    11 200.    2.6          1.70          1.10
```

**4. Creating Model lm using transformed variables**

```
first_model <- caret::train(form = sales ~ var1_transfrm + var2_transfrm, 
                            data = df_test,
                            method = "lm")

# for Rsquare value
first_model$results$Rsquared
```

**[1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hC0CKNjv9SM&list=PLdaWFt7A-Gf22hlttVYYoR0HlJ-B7OYwo&index=9) 0.8952383**

I need to find the best Rsquare/ minimum RMSE,MAE value above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I am new to `optimization` techniques so it took me a while to research and post an answer but I am glad that I could find the answer to my problem and able to use `r` built in functions only rather than any other to solve this.

```
test_excel_solver <- function(params, df_optim){
  
  alpha1 = params[1]
  alpha2 = params[2]
  beta1 = params[3]
  beta2 = params[4]
  
  # transforming variables using a,b parameters that need to figured out
  df_optim_tranfm <- df_optim %>% 
  mutate(var1_transfrm = var1^alpha1,
         var1_transfrm = if_else(row_number() == 1, 
                               var1^alpha1,
                               ( (var1 + lag(var1_transfrm)*beta1)^alpha1 )
                               ) ,
         
         var2_transfrm = var2^alpha2,
         var2_transfrm = if_else(row_number() == 1, 
                               var2^alpha2,
                               ( (var2 + lag(var2_transfrm)*beta2)^alpha2 )
                               ) 
         )
         
  # setting seed for lm
  set.seed(2022)
  
  
  # creating model
  model_optim <- lm(sales ~ var1_transfrm+var2_transfrm, data = df_optim_tranfm)
  
  # predicted values
  y_hat = predict(model_optim, df_optim_tranfm)

  # MAE that we need to minimize using optim
  MAE <- mean(abs(df_optim_tranfm$sales - y_hat))
  MAE
  
}

# Using optim function 
optim(par = c(.1,.1,.1,.1), # initializing alpha1=.1,alpha2=.1 & so on till beta2=.1
      df_optim = df_test,
      fn = test_excel_solver, 
      lower = c(.00001,.00001,.00001,.00001),
      upper = c(1,1,1,1),
      method = "L-BFGS-B")
```

Output

```
$par
[1] 0.9116201 0.9687086 0.0000100 1.0000000

$value
[1] 1.378359

$counts
function gradient 
      98       98 

$convergence
[1] 52

$message
[1] "ERROR: ABNORMAL_TERMINATION_IN_LNSRCH"
```

P.S:

1. I am not sure about the method used & differences in other options provided to optimize.
2. This took me just 1-2 seconds to run.
3. I also ran without optimization/optim() in a for loop which took me more than 1 hour when I used 14 cores, so optimization technique helped me alot in time saving & computation.

Answer (score 0):

Linear programming is not a good tool to find least squares solutions. Maximizing R^2 implies minimizing the RSS (Residual Sum of Squares).

In theory, you could form the so-called normal equations, but this is not numerically stable.

Least-squares leads to a quadratic optimization problem and can be solved that way. Of course, R has good, numerically stable algorithms for least squares regression. It is better to use those methods.

The video you referred to is **not** using linear programming, but rather a non-linear optimizer (GRG).

Comment: Yes you are right @Erwin, its using non linear optimizer GRG and I have been thinking about using Gradient descent for this but also came across **Nevergrad** by facebook for such optimizations.

Comment: And I think I need to modify my question as you have rightly pointed about non linear optimization.